# On key pressed multiple times

Tags: c#, keyboard

I need to make different commands on <kbd>Escape</kbd> key pressed, for example

```
if Escape key is once pressed .. Draw(250,250);
if Escape key is twice pressed .. Draw(350,350);
if Escape key is triple pressed .. Draw(450,450);
```

on one key I have to have multiple different commands, 
how to make the app to count how many times a key is pressed and using that info .. to run a specific code?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a counter and increment it each time the key is pressed.
If you are talking about double or triple "clicking", you also need to set a `Timer`.
Each time the timer ends, you reset your counter.

Only thing left is to call the method you want depending on your counter value.

```
int MyKeyCounter = 0;
Timer CounterResetter = new Timer(1000);
CounterResetter.Elapsed += ResetCounter;

void OnKeyPressEvent(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
        MyKeyCounter++;
        if(!CounterResetter.Enabled)
            CounterResetter.Start();
    }
}

void ResetCounter(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if(MyKeyCounter == 1)
        Method1();
    else if (MyKeyCounter == 2)
        Method2();
    ...

    MyKeyCounter = 0;
}
```

Attach the event on the control you want and put the fields at the top.

Comment: NB: I don't have VS here so it's not accurate code, let me a few minutes to check MSDN.

Comment: I think it should be OK now

Comment: hmm, there is no elapsed option under timer.. :/

Comment: Are you using winforms' `Timer` ? In this case the event is called `Tick` instead of `Elapsed`. Also if this is winforms `ElapsedEventArgs `should be replaced by `EventArgs`

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way I can think of. It waits for the user to input a key, and counts it
if its the escape key. Any other key pressed breaks the loop, then you count the times pressed!

```
        ConsoleKeyInfo key;
        int timesPressed = 0;
        while(true) {
            key = Console.ReadKey();
            if (!key.Equals( ConsoleKey.Escape ) || timesPressed >= 3) {
                break;
            }
            timesPressed++;
        }
```